# Difficulty to reach Mach 1 by blowing into a small converging-diverging nozzle?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics

I'm learning about the basics of converging/diverging nozzles in my thermodynamics class, and it has me curious. Could you theoretically blow into a tiny converging/diverging nozzle and break the sound barrier, or do other effects prevent that from happening?

Assuming one could blow 10MPH, dividing by the speed of sound in Wolfram gives me: 
M=0.013
Using an online calculator I get 
A/A*=45
Using the width of a straw being 7.5mm (sorry for mixing units, but M is unitless so no harm done) I get 
A*=1.25mm, or ~
D*=1.25mm

Which seems like something you could realistically 3D print. I saw somewhere that Lulzbot claims an xy precision of .05mm, so I would imagine the tolerance would be a manageable issue. However, I assume there's something I'm missing. I've heard somewhere that there's a fourth power relation between the width of arteries and the ability to push blood through. Is that an incompressible substance relation, or can I apply that here?

I also notice that my textbook uses a few assumptions, such as ideal gas relations and isentropic flow. I believe air should behave ideally in this range, but isentropic implies frictionless (right?), and I'm not sure this would apply with such a small 3D printed part, or such a large change in speed.

TL;DR can you reach choke flow through a converging/diverging nozzle with Ai = Ae = the cross sectional area of a straw?

Comment: Are you sure mixing units is good practice? It is a **very** bad habit to get into imho (all to easy to not use Kelvin when needed...). Why not convert MPH into m/s...

Comment: I wouldn't do it for something that mattered, but those were the units of the information I gathered. In short, I did it for (part of) the same reason I used 2-3 sig figs through calculations, there's just no severity in this problem. I try to treat problems with the attention I feel they deserve

Comment: Your choice, but I would always take the questions and sort the units to a coherent set of values as the first step. Then I was able to focus on the question and use the equations as necessary without having to stop to consider any unit conversions "mid-flow"...

Comment: I admit I see totally see the merit in that. I should explain that for short problems like this, where I can plug the entire problem into Wolfram, units are somewhat irrelevant. I'm solving symbolically and allowing Wolfram to convert the values I paste in. Changing units would just be silly because Wolfram sees them as identical -- it would only allow for potential rounding/algebraic/copying errors. If I were to need a script or a pencil to tackle this problem, I would absolutely convert to the most convenient unit system and stick with it from beginning to end.

Comment: But can you blow 10mph into a straw with that kind of restriction? Could Dizzy Gillespie?

Comment: Well that's my question. But in theory, you could be blowing 10mph (I read that people can blow 15, so not a crazy leap) then quickly move the straw in front of your face. There would be some 10mph air entering the straw, but after that is the crux of the issue.

Comment: @Tyler Think of it this way. You have two lungs full of air, and your mouth and some other object are combining to for a convergent nozzle. What is the Pressure Ratio between lungs and outside needed to get to Mach 1? (eq. [10.25](https://web.stanford.edu/~cantwell/AA210A_Course_Material/AA210A_Course_Notes/AA210_Fundamentals_of_Compressible_Flow_Ch_10_BJ_Cantwell.pdf) ).

Comment: And no, you can't do it with a tiny orifice because you have a fully viscous boundary layer. You need several mm throat diameter and good design to be able to use ideal gas approximations.

Comment: And your suggestion to use "air hammer" won't work because you'd need enough momentum in the straw to compress some of the air at the throat to the needed pressure ratio. Compressibility really works against trying to do this.

Comment: If my math is right, it looks like it would require about 1MPa, which looks to be about 5 times the capabilities of the average person. But that's also assuming a constant value of gamma and isentropic conditions, which obviously changes as you suggested it would. To deal with the "air hammer" failures I imagine you could bring the straw near vacuum with your mouth, seal the ends, then air hammer again to avoid the compressibility issues with air already inside the straw.

Comment: Also, how does the full viscous boundary layer work against this exactly? That boundary layer exists in all nozzle problems, so why does it begin to fail around "several mm diameter"? As far as my basic fluid mechanics class is concerned, the velocity gradient will hold the same shape regardless of width, so that 'shouldn't' change anything. Why is this not the case in practice? Does compressibility make a difference here? I don't recall all of the assumptions we made in that class, but I know they should fail at smaller sizes, because in classes we treat molecules like infinitesimals